# Paste special without using clipboard

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste a range of data from one file to another. but this is affecting the format of the destination file. Request your help.

Below is a part of the code that I am using:

```
    Dim repdata As Range

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("file name")

    Set repdata = Range("A2", Cells(lastrow, lastcol))

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("file2")

    repdata.Copy Destination:=Range("B8")
```

But this is overwriting the format in the destination.

I tried :

```
    repdata.Copy Destination:=Range("B8").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues).
```

This is not working. Its giving error

I also tried

```
    repdata.Copy Destination:=Range("B8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues.
```

Even this is not working. Its giving error

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Value = repdata.Value`? If that doesn't work, `ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Resize` first, to match the destination number of rows, and assign the `.Value` of the resized range. `{Range}.Copy Destination:={target}`  works just like manual pasting: it pastes the values, the formats, the borders, the conditional formats, everything.

Comment: *'This is not working. Its giving error'* is not considered an actual error code nor an accurate description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give you a definitive answer, because you didn't post your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - should be something you should keep in mind in future questions.

---

To answer your question, the axe most likely lies here - Don't use `Destination` with `PasteSpecial`
This should work fine, presuming everything else in your code is functional.

```
Dim repdata As Range
Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("file name")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("file2")
Set repdata = wb1.Range("A2", Cells(lastrow, lastcol))

repdata.Copy
wb2.Range("B8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: @user3228901 No problem. Mark the answer as the "Solution"  then please, so the question will get closed in a sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of direct value transfer that will not affect the destination formatting.

```
dim wb as workbook, wb1 as workbook
Dim repdata As Range, lastrow as long, lastcol as long

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("file name")

with wb1.worksheets("sheet")
    lastrow = .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row
    lastcol = .cells(2, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column

    with .Range(.cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("file2")
        wb.worksheets("sheetx").cells(8, "B").resize(.rows.count..columns.count) = .value
    end with
end with
```

It's not considered 'best practice' to rely on the activesheet property of a newly opened workbook. Reference your worksheets properly, even if that means using worksheets(1) for a single worksheet workbook.

Comment: Hi Jeeped... Thanks for your help. Will try this one as well for a different file.