# Copy range of cells and paste it in sequence using offset

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple range of cells in Sheet1. I wanted to copy this entire range of cells and paste it in the next position just bypass one column.  Then I wanted to automatic change the date to the next date.

Please see snip image.[image]

Code so far:

```
Sub Copy()

Range("A1:D5").Copy Range("F1:I5")
Range("I3:I5").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paste special without using clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067024/paste-special-without-using-clipboard)

Comment: Hi Sir. I would like to paste the range of cell in the same worksheet only leaving 1 column.  Everytime I click the button, it will paste the cell in the next sequence.

Comment: Well... instead of declaring the second worksheet like in the linked example, simply paste the data to the same one *(thought that was a pretty obvious intuition...)*

Comment: What does the "next sequence" mean. What does "Next Position" mean. What does "Bypass one column" mean. What "Next date" and which date are you talking about? The one in the original range or the one in the pasted range. Please clarify your question using excel terms and your example screenshot "Sequence", "Position", and "Bypass" are not excel words so they are meaningless without some definition.

Comment: Basically If I click the button, it will paste the range of cell to the same sheet on the right side bypassing 1 column. (Please see snip image).  If I click the button again, it will do the same thing onto the next range of cell.  Then of course the day will change example June 1 to June 2.

Comment: If you click it again it will paste it into the "next range of cell"... What "next range" what does that mean? Another block/range starting at `K1`? Please try to be explicit. You clicked the button again... which range is being copied? The range starting at `F1` or the one starting `A1`? It's not at all clear what you want to have happen. Why would the new range in `K1` get `June 2nd`. Wouldn't it be `June 3rd` because you already increased the date in range `F1` in the first button click. Perhaps post three pictures. 1) starting state 2) state after 1st click 3) state after 3rd click.

Comment: Sorry for that Sir..Let's imagine range A1:D5 as the only table there, if I click the button, it will copy to range F1:I5 then the date will be June 2.  If I click again the button it will copy the same table to range K1:N5 then date will be June 3. something like that Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rCopy As Range
    Dim rDest As Range
    Dim dtLastDate As Date

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set rCopy = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set rDest = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 2)
    dtLastDate = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value2

    rCopy.Copy rDest
    ws.Cells(3, rDest.Column + rCopy.Columns.Count - 1).Resize(rCopy.Rows.Count - 2).ClearContents
    rDest.Cells(1, 1).Value = dtLastDate + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Buddy @ tigeravatar, that actually works. Thank you so much..I have a bit of question, if I wanted to extend my rows of original table up to 20 rows. What to change their in the code?

Comment: @ArerrabFearmoreNayr No change needed, the `.CurrentRegion` will already adjust to however many rows of data are in your table.

Comment: Hi Sir TigerAvatar, you really help me a lot Sir. This makes my team mates daily task to be more faster.  I have another co-worker where she needs to copy and paste a table (4 rows, 10 column). She needs to paste it going down. I will look your code Sir and study. If  Ihave issue Sir I will connect with you.